# How can I replace '_' to single quotation for MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to submit some values from radio button and input box from my form. There will some value like A-level, O-level, M-course etc. I want when I insert them in MySQL database after submit form, that value will convert " - " to " ' " (single quotation). I want to change both of them

```
<form action="action.php">
<input type="radio" name="course" value="A-level" />
<input type="radio" name="course" value="O-level" />
<input type="text" name="title"/>
<input type="submit" name="myform" />
</form>
```

My databese table name course_table, column name "course_name", "courst_title". 
Database will get like: A'level, O'level
Please help me to insert them and if possible give me full code
Thank You

Comment: Use str_replace to switch characters. The database code can be found if you just seach using any popular search Engine.

Comment: This is a really strange way of going about things, and almost certainly not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
echo str_replace("-","'","O-level");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, in PHP you need to insert into the database:

```
if($_GET['myform']) {
    $course = str_replace("-", "'", $_GET["course"]);
    insert into table (course) values ($course);
}
```